# Load HTML content on Aspx page Dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to generate a page with HTML sent via parameter, but I have no idea how to do it.
For exemple: I'm creating the whole HTML code on the page 'page1.aspx' and I want to show this content on another page, 'page2.aspx', preferably in another tab.
Is there a way to do this?
I'd like not to create a new aspx file everytime I do this, rather, use the same page2.aspx file and just replace the content dynamically.

Comment: Mostly, I tried messing with routes, but the data that I maneged to get thourhg is not enough to build the page, that's why I decided to send the whole HTML code.
I also tried saving the page content to database and loading it on page_load, but this really eats up my database, since this will be done repeatedly. The ideal thing for me would be to send the whole html as a string to the new page. I really don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Can you store it in `Session` or `Cache` on page1 and load it in page2?

Comment: I don't think so. The page will be linked on an Email that I'll send to a customer. They won't have access to a server session or cache.

Comment: You can have a link in email and that link with param say id=2, when that page opens up, it will look for id = 2 in DB and render the HTML stored in DB in aspx page.

Comment: I managed to get it working yesterday and that's exactly how i did it @ArindamNayak